# Indent all table rows but not table headers CSS

Tags: html, css

How could I indent all of the items in an HTML table using only css.

```
Header
    Item1
    Item2
    ...
```

Comment: `padding-left`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```css
table td:first-child{
  padding-left:30px;
}
table th{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Indentation can be changed by changing `padding-left:30px`.

Comment: I found a way for the border! :  border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: <indent amount> 0;